# Noncompactness of $SL_n(\mathbb R)/SL_n(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

For $n\ge 2$, I saw from a paper that $SL_n(\mathbb R)/SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is noncompact. I wonder how to prove this fact. If the proof for the general case $n\ge 2$ is too complicated, I am also glad to learn the proof just for the case $n=2$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sketch of a proof: $SL_n(\mathbb{R}) / SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$  parametrizes lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with fundamental domain of volume $1$.  To see this is non-compact just consider the lattices $L(r)$ generated by $\frac{1}{r}e_1, \frac{1}{r}e_2, \dots, \frac{1}{r}e_{n-1}$, and $r^{n-1}e_n$ where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.  As $r \to \infty$ this sequence of lattices does not approach any sort of limit (or have any convergent subsequence) and therefore the space of lattices must be non-compact.

Comment: I don't know the topology on the space of lattices and the correspondence you mentioned should involve lots of theories. But I think in elementary language, what you wrote is just that equivalence class of $diag(r^{n-1}, 1/r, ..., 1/r)$ does not converge in this quotient topology. It looks true to me but I can't think of a way to make it rigorous...

Comment: So seeing that this parametrizes lattices of covolume 1 is fairly straightforward: 
 $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of covolume 1, and the stabilizer of the standard lattice is $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.  Therefore we can identify $SL_n(\mathbb{R})/SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with this set of lattices.  As for rigorously checking that this family I mentioned doesn't converge try looking at the quantity $min_B(max_{v \in B} ||v||))$ where $B$ is running over bases for the lattice.

Comment: So how is the topology on lattices defined exactly that accommodates the convergence you defined?

Comment: You write "does not approach any sort of limit": indeed it does, just the limit is not a lattice. Actually the Chabauty topology on the set of closed subgroups of $\mathbf{R}^n$ forms a compact space, in which the set of lattices is open and dense. For this topology, the limit of $L(r)$ when $r\to\infty$ is $\mathbf{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Not only is $SL_n(\mathbb R)/SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ noncompact, there is a well known criterion (called [Mahler's compactness criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_compactness_theorem)) which gives a necessary and sufficient condition of when a subset $A\subset SL_n(\mathbb R)/SL_n(\mathbb Z)$  is compact.

You can read a nice proof in the book 'An introduction to the geometry of numbers' by J.W.S Cassels, which also helps understand why this set it noncompact.